# Write a one-liner function to return a random integer with decreasing chances as it gets higher

Tags: random

I am a computer programmer and I would like to write a simple formula that would return a random integer, but I’d like to decrease the chance of getting a value as it increases.

i.e., if I want to get an integer between 1 and 4, I would like this integer to have 4 chances to be 1, 3 chances to be 2, 2 chances to be 3 and 1 to be 4.

Intuitively, a way to write this program would be to do this:

```
var array = []
var currentCount = maxBound
for (i in 1…maxBound) {
     var j = 0
     while (j < currentCount) {
         array.append(i)
         j += 1
     }
     currentCount -= 1
}
// result would be a random element from array
```

I would like to find instead a one-liner way of writing it, supposed I have a function `random(low,high)` that returns any value between low and high.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This probably belongs to stackoverflow? Or is there some mathematics-specific question that you want to ask?

Comment: @Trebor The coding part belongs probably to SO, however the methodology and algorithm behind could be a good fit for here.

Comment: And in case of the `low` and `high` values equal to - say - $15$ and $19$ the probability of getting in order respectively $15,16,17,18,19$ should be proportional to $19,18,17,16,15$? (Or to $5,4,3,2,1$? Or to something else?) Any programming language is accepted, including pseudocode? Or there are some special preferences? May the solution already involve a random number generator (e.g. of a random number between zero and one) - or the one-liner should do the job from the scratch? Please mention some more details, maybe even the special purpose for the question and the range to be used, too.

Answer (score 0):

In Python (and probably in most other programming languages) there is the option that you can provide weights for a random generator. So in your case a simple python solution would be

```
import numpy as np
draw = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 5), size=1,p=np.arange(4, 0, -1)/np.sum(np.arange(4, 0, -1)))
```

This will draw an integer $1\leq m < 5$ while the probability is reversely distributed, i.e. $1$ has weight $4$, $2$ has weight $3$ and so on. The division is necessary so that the sum of all probabilities is exactly $1$.